# How to find a Thomas Cook flight number?

Tags: air-travel, flight-status, thomas-cook

I need to find Thomas cook flight number from Manchester, UK to Dalaman, Turkey on September 21st and 22nd, 2013.

Is there a tool to find flight numbers of past Thomas Cook airline flights?

Answer (score 3):

Via the [Thomas Cook airlines website](http://www.thomascookairlines.com) I found that the flight on September 21 has the number TCX2354 and on September 22 it has the number TCX2774.

Comment: If you just look up a flight from Manchester to Dalaman on September 21 using that site, you get the flight number for September 21, 2015.  The question is asking about the flight number for September 21, 2013 - almost two years ago.  Unless you know more than you included in your answer, I don't see any reason for confidence that the flight number stays the same from year to year.